# What is the domain of $f(x)= x!$?

Tags: calculus

Is the domain of function $x$ factorial $(0, \infty)$ because factorial is defined by $x$ greater or equal to than $0$.

If this function is graphed in the complex plane, would the domain be different than the reals, would the domain be $(-\infty, \infty)$?

Comment: if factorial strictly, it's only counting/natural numbers, including 0. So 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.

if it's the gamma function, it's all reals minus negative integers

Comment: If we are talking about the factorial function, $x!$ is defined only for $x \in \mathbb N$. What you are looking for seems to be the Gamma Function.

Comment: (1) Part of a function's definition is its domain.  It doesn't make sense to ask "what is the domain" of some formula.  (2)  That being said, it can make sense to ask about the **largest** set of numbers on which a formula makes sense, or the most **natural** set of numbers on which a formula make sense.  In this case, it is the nonnegative integers.  (3) It is also reasonable to ask if a function can be extended to a larger domain.  In this case, the factorial function extends to a holomorphic function, called the Gamma function (other extensions are possible).

Answer (score 2):

The factorial is usually just defined in $\mathbb{N}_0$... However it can be extended using the $\Gamma$ function ($n! = \Gamma(n+1)$), to the whole complex plane, except for negative integers.